# Инициализация объекта без new

Tags: c#

Объявить класс `Dictionary` можно так:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1, "..."},
    ...
};
```

Как сделать так, чтобы я мог инициализировать свой класс подобным образом?

```
List<MyClass> l = new List
{
    {...} // Инициализация моего класса
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Чтобы работал такой неявный инициализатор нужно добавить инициализируемому классу метод Add с параметрами, соответствующими тому, что будет в квадратных скобках. Например, если у вас есть класс MyClass, у которого конструктор от двух строк и вы хотите легко инициализировать список таких классов, то придется завести класс для списка:

```
class MyClassList : List<MyClass>
{
   public void Add(string s1, string s2)
   {
       Add(new MyClass(s1, s2));
   }
}
```

теперь Вы получаете возможность инициализировать свой список так:

```
List<MyClass> l = new MyClassList() 
{ {"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"} };
```

Comment: Благодарю!